# XSD string pattern independent of leading/trailing space

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I have a XSD simple type that should match UUIDs:

```
<simpleType name="UuidT">
    <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

It correctly matches the following content:

```
<!-- valid -->
<Uuid>12345678-1234-5678-9012-123456789012</Uuid>
```

But it doesn't match content that contains excess whitespace:

```
<!-- not valid -->
<Uuid>
    2de25a81-b117-4b2a-b910-50f0878884f7
</Uuid>
```

Sure, I could add `\s*` to both sides of the regex, but isn't there a simpler solution in XSD?

Comment: Is it the "xsi:token" type? Seems to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `restriction base="xs:token"`.

Comment: The W3C tutorials (http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_string.asp) say that it does the same as `<whiteSpace value="collapse"/>`, i.e. replacing all whitespace with spaces and multiple whitespace with single space. Seems like there's no exact solution to my problem, but token will work.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp), you should define

```
<xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
```

(possibly without the namespace)

Comment: This works, but that replaces all whitespace by spaces, no matter whether is leading/trailing or in the middle of the content. Might not always be what I want (but it's okay in this case).